# Run a shell script upon connection to port 445

Tags: iptables

My machine currently has port 445 open to the internet. I'm looking to see how frequent scans of this port are and I plan to achieve that by running a shell script when someone connects to this port. How could I do this with IPtables? I'm using Debian 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is very old, but doesn't involve iptables.  It's called the [inetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) super-server.  Its configuration - /etc/inetd.conf - lets you define the port and protocol to listen for - the "service", defined in /etc/services - and the program to execute in case of a connection - which could be your logging script.

The service would be

```
microsoft-ds    445/tcp                         # Microsoft Naked CIFS
```

Comment: I recall this from years ago... I assumed it had been deprecated, but it's still available as `inetutils-inetd` in Debian. I wonder if you could do the same thing with `systemd-networkd`?

Comment: Sorry, I keep as far away from systemd as possible.

Comment: @Seamus Not with `systemd-networkd`, but by defining a systemd `.socket` unit and a corresponding `.service` unit.

Comment: @telcoM: That might make a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can't start programs or scripts from IPtables, but you can log traffic that comes to some port in IPtables.

This will log entry in system log (/var/log/syslog on Debian) every time something comes to udp or tcp port 445 with log prefix and details about the connection (timestamp, source port, source IP, ...)

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 445 -j LOG --log-prefix "PORT 445 connnection!!"
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 445 -j LOG --log-prefix "PORT 445 connnection!!"
```

If you want to start some script when something comes on port 445 you would need to use inetd or on Debian 10 you can also use systemd socket to start a script through a service when something comes to port 445.

Depending what you want it would be better that you just log connections to port 445 in log and run a script on some schedule that will count the entries in log or extract them.